# Trouble using conditional statements with type def struct variables

Tags: c, struct, typedef, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm having trouble using decision statements with type def struct variables,
also i cant declare the variables to equal zero anywhere.

Here is the struct

```
typedef struct{
    int wallet;
    int account;
}MONEY;
```

It was declared in main as `MONEY money;` (but for the function im having
 trouble with its *m)

When i try to do something like this

```
*m.wallet = *m.wallet - depositAmmount;
```

or this

```
*m.wallet = 0;
```

It gives me a syntax error saying expression must have a class type.
What do i do? Inside the function I tried declaring int `*m.wallet = 0;`and even `DATE *m.wallet;` to no avail

below is the whole function

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define clear system("clear") 
#define pause system("pause") 
void banking(MONEY *m){
    int userChoice = 0;
    int withdrawAmmount = 0;
    int depositAmmount = 0;
    do{
        userChoice = 0;
        withdrawAmmount = 0;
        depositAmmount = 0;
        displayBankMenu(*m);
        scanf("%i", &userChoice);
        clear;

        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                    printf("How much would you like to Deposit?: $");
                    scanf("%i", &depositAmmount);
                    if(depositAmmount <= *m.wallet){
                        *m.wallet = *m.wallet - depositAmmount;
                        *m.account = *m.account + depositAmmount;
                    }else{
                        printf("You do not have sufficient funds for this transaction.");
                        pause;
                    }

                    break;
            case 2:                 
                    printf("How much would you like to withdraw?: $");
                    scanf("%i", &withdrawAmmount);
                    if(withdrawAmmount <= *m.account){
                        *m.account = *m.account - withdrawAmmount;
                        *m.wallet = *m.wallet + withdrawAmmount;
                    } else{
                        printf("You do not have sufficient funds for this transaction.");
                        pause;
                    }

                    userChoice = 0;

                    break;
        }
    }while(userChoice != 3);
} //end banking
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a member of a pointer to a structure, use the `->` operator.

```
m->wallet = m->wallet - depositAmmount;
m->wallet = 0;
```

The `.` operator has higher precedence than the `*` dereference, so you need to use parentheses for that expression to obtain the structure member.

```
(*m).wallet = (*m).wallet - depositAmmount;
(*m).wallet = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now and i will remember the second part for future reference ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Structure member operator `.` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`. So the following statement

```
*m.wallet = 0;
```

is the same as

```
*(m.wallet) = 0;
```

It means get the member `wallet` of the struct `m` and then dereference it, assuming it's a pointer. But `m` is a pointer to the structure, not the structure itself. So you should first dereference the pointer to get the structure and then use `.` operator to get the `wallet` member.

```
(*m).wallet = 0;
```

You can also use the more convenient arrow operator `->` as

```
m->wallet = 0;
```

They are the same.